# Trace of product of three matrices

Tags: matrices, trace, hermitian-matrices

I have an expression of the form
\begin{equation}
i\operatorname{tr}(ABC - B^\dagger AC),
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $C$ are Hermitian matrices, but $B$ is not. $B-B^\dagger := i D$, where $D$ is also a Hermitian matrix. It can be seen that the above is real by cyclic permutation of the second term inside the trace, $B^\dagger AC \to CB^\dagger A$:
$$
i\operatorname{tr}(ABC - CB^\dagger A) = i \underbrace{\operatorname{tr}(ABC - (ABC)^\dagger)}_{2 i \operatorname{Im} (\operatorname{tr}(ABC))}=-2\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{tr}(ABC))\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
However, for reasons concerning the specific form of the matrices, I would like to rewrite the first expression like so:
\begin{align}
i\operatorname{tr}(ABC - B^\dagger AC)
&= i\operatorname{tr}(ABC - B^\dagger CA + B^\dagger \left[C,A\right])\\
&= i \operatorname{tr}(ABC - A B^\dagger C) - i\operatorname{tr}(B^\dagger \left[A,C\right])\\
&= - \operatorname{tr}(ADC) - i \operatorname{tr}(B^\dagger \left[A,C\right]),
\end{align}
where $\left[A,C\right]$ is the commutator of $A$ and $C$. My (perhaps minor) issue is that it is not readily apparent (to me at least) that the final expression is also real. Is there a way of seeing explicitly that the final expression is real, without knowing the specifics of A, B and C and without just rewriting it to its original form?

Comment: That's an error on my part. It's supposed to say $[A,C]$, not $[C,A]$. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hermitian conjugate is the composition of the complex conjugate
and the transpose
$$\eqalign{
\def\d{\dagger}
&Z^\d \;\equiv\; (Z^*)^T \;\equiv\; (Z^T)^* \\
}$$
Hermitian matrices satisfy
$$\eqalign{
&A^\d = A \quad\implies\quad A^T=A^* \\
&C^\d = C \quad\implies\quad C^T=C^* \\
}$$
The double-dot product $(:)$ is a convenient notation for the **trace** and has these properties
$$\eqalign{
\def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\beta} \def\l{\lambda}
\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
X:Y \;&\equiv\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^n X_{ik}Y_{ik} \;\equiv\; \tr(X^TY) \\
X:Y &= Y:X \;=\; Y^T:X^T \\
PQ:Y &= P:(YQ^T) \;=\; Q:(P^TY) \\
}$$
Use the above notations to analyze the first expression
$$\eqalign{
&\tr(ABC) = AB:C^T = B:A^TC^T = B:(AC)^* &\equiv \l \\
&\tr(B^\d AC) = B^*:AC = \Big(B:(AC)^*\Big)^* &\equiv \l^* \\
&\l \;\equiv\; \a+i\b \quad\iff\quad \l^* = \a-i\b \\
&\therefore \;i\tr(ABC-B^\d AC) \;=\; i(\l-\l^*) \;\equiv\; -2\b \\
}$$
and (the negative of) the second
$$\eqalign{
&\tr(ADC) = D^T:CA = D:(AC)^* = iB^\d:(AC)^*-iB:(AC)^* \\
&\tr(ADC) \equiv i\mu-i\l \\
&i\tr(B^\d AC-B^\d CA) = iB^*:AC - iB^\d:(AC)^* \;\equiv\; i\l^* - i\mu \\
&\therefore\;\tr(ADC)+i\tr(B^\d[AC]) = i(\l^*-\l) \;\equiv\; 2\b \\
}$$
So your first and second expressions are equal and are real.

Comment: Thanks you for your solution, and thank you for introducing me to this notation.